# How to prevent XML-DML modify function adding empty namespaces to the inserting nodes

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, xml-dml

So basically I have a script that updates XML based on whether such node exists or not.
Here's the t-sql

```
DECLARE @newJob XML
SET @newJob = N'<job>
    <job-detail>
      <name>job-name</name>
    </job-detail>
  </job>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData')
UPDATE XmlTable
SET ConfigXml.modify('
insert sql:variable("@newJob") 
as last into (/quartz)[1]')
WHERE ConfigXml.exist(N'//quartz/job/job-detail/name[.="job-name"]') = 0
```

Now everything works as expected except only the inserted  node now contains empty namespace like this

```
<job xmlns="">
```

If I remove

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData')
```

query stops executing. I think this is because my root node has namespaces defined

```
<quartz xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" overwrite-existing-jobs="true">
```

So my question is - is there any way to prevent this namespace addition to the node that is being inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To overcome this problem I slightly changed the approach, in particular I'm declaring xml namespaces in xml-dml modify function itself, and adding namespace prefixes to the inserting nodes. That did the trick

```
UPDATE XmlTable
SET ConfigXml.modify('
declare namespace ns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData";
insert <ns:job>
    <ns:job-detail>
      <ns:name>jobName</ns:name>
    </ns:job-detail>
  </ns:job>
as last into (/ns:quartz)[1]')
WHERE ConfigXml.exist(N'
declare namespace ns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData";
//ns:quartz/ns:job/ns:job-detail/ns:name[.="jobName"]') = 0
```

Hope this helps someone else.